# Get category-ID of overview of featured articles

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm trying to get the category id's of a site listing multiple featured articles.
`JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInt('catid');` works fine if the site contains just an article.

Is there something similar for featured articles?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not get it from the input, because the categories are not set into the request for featured view.

What you can do is to use the parameters of active menu item to retrieve them. Like this:

```
$activeMenu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();
$categories = $activeMenu->params->get('featured_categories');
var_dump($categories);
```

The result is an array with categories ids:

```
array(2) 
{ 
    [0]=> string(2) "19" 
    [1]=> string(2) "20" 
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This works perfect!